# generation of random 10 in unity c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Audio clips come null. So how to fill array correctly by using elements of sounds?

Please help me the below code:

```
using UnityEngine; 
using System.Collections; 

public class Audio_RanGen: MonoBehaviour {
    public AudioClip[] sounds;

    // Use this for initialization 
    void Start() {
        sounds=new AudioClip[5];
        // you would need to create/assign for your audio clip here 
    }

    // Update is called once per frame 
    void Update() {
    }

    void OnGUI() {
        if(GUI.Button(new Rect(100, 200, 200, 50), "Random Number Genaration")) {
            audio.clip=sounds[Random.Range(0, 4)];
            print(audio.clip);
            audio.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it audioclip array contains null so wt i can do..

Comment: how to create audioclip in my above script give one example plz

Answer (score 0):

You must use Random.Range function. Here is the link to the manual.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html

Comment: AudioClip[] sound =new AudioClip[]; // how to set the array size and how to fill the elements with the soundsto this array

Comment: @kittureddy you assign audioclip elements from the editor by dragging them from project view

Answer (score 0):

In Unity3D you don't need to assign the public array if you are doing it from the editor ( It's assigned from Unity3D when the component is initialized ).
So remove the following line:

```
sounds = new AudioClip[5];
```

And assign the `AudioClip`s from the editor. If you now want to play a random audio file i suggest using the following line:

```
audio.clip = sounds[Random.Range(0, sounds.Length * 7) % sounds.Length];
```

Which results in a better random seed than just using the initial length of the array and the code must not be changed every time when you update the arrays data.

If you've not used Unity3D frequently i would suggest reading some tutorials. Especially [this one](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/UsingTheInspector.html).

If you don't want to create the `AudioClip` items by code: There are several ways to do this and the most could be found when [using google](https://www.google.de/search?q=unity3d%20load%20audio%20clip&aq=0&oq=unity3d%20load%20au&aqs=chrome.1.57j0l3j62.3699j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). But then you need to assign the sounds array by default.

Comment: how to create/assign for our audio clip plz help me creation of audo clip give one example

Comment: @kittureddy You don't need to assign it, just use Unity3D, add the component to one object and assign the variables in the property inspector.

Comment: yes i can do it but it come null values to audioclip...components->audio->audiosource -here drag and drop the sound file but it comes null values ..in this procedure is correct or not?

Comment: @kittureddy Step-by-step: Add the audio files you want to your unity-scene ->> Drag and drop your behaviour on a unity-object ->> Drag and drop all sounds into the array `sounds`. Finished. Now you don NOT need to assign `sounds` with `new AudioClip[5]` and no further work is required. Be careful, if a sound is removed the reference might be null!

Comment: the above code contains in this error remove error::Cannot implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.Object[]' to `UnityEngine.AudioClip[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)